# How selected item MVVM listview - Xamarin form

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

how to select item in listview Mvvm my code did't working

my code Itemsource:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllCamps();
        lstCampus.ItemsSource = allPersons;
    }
```

my code selectedItem:

```
void OnItemTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstCampus.SelectedItem != null)
            DisplayAlert("OnItemTapped", lstCampus.SelectedItem.ToString(), "OK");
    }
```

my model :

```
public class Campus
{
    public string NameCamp { get; set; }
}
```

my view model:

```
public async Task<List<Campus>> GetAllCamps()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Camps")
          .OnceAsync<Campus>()).Select(item => new Campus
          {
              NameCamp = item.Object.NameCamp
          }).ToList();
    }
```

Thank u

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use behaviours. This will help you:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-eventtocommand-behavior-in-mvvm-viewmodel/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior

After that just add something like this to your list:

```
                <ListView.Behaviors>
                    <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding TappedCamp}" InputConverter="{StaticResource ItemTappedConverter}"/>
                </ListView.Behaviors>
```